# Convirtiendo Collection de VB a C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

En una conversión de `vb.net` a `C#` tengo la siguiente Linea:

```
Public Function getImageData(ByVal sImageID As String, ByVal rutaConfiguracionImagenes As String)
Dim caracteristicasImagenes As New ArrayList
Try
    Dim datosImagenes As Collection = ReadXML(rutaConfiguracionImagenes)
    sImageData = CType(datosImagenes.Item(sImageID), ImageData) '.... demás código
```

Al convertir a C#:

```
public ArrayList getImageData(string sImageID, string rutaConfiguracionImagenes)
{
    ArrayList caracteristicasImagenes = new ArrayList();
    try
    {
        List<object> datosImagenes = ReadXML(rutaConfiguracionImagenes);
        sImageData = (ImageData)datosImagenes.Item[sImageID];//Item da error
```

Estoy usando convertidor `vb to c# de telerik` el error que muestra es el siguiente:

> 'List' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no
>   accessible extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type
>   'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

**Nota:** en `vb` *datosImagenes* esta como `Collection` y en `c#` lo convertí a `list<object>`

Comment: List no contiene la propiedad Item, para ello sería `datosImages[sImageId]` [List<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Prueba con esto `(ImageData)datosImagenes[sImageID];` creo que es lo que estas intentado.

Comment: Tener presente que el indexador de una List<T> solo admite un `int` y no un `string` como `sImageId`. El parametro `sImageId` debe ser un entero.

Comment: Correcto Orlando `sImageID` debe ser un int.

Comment: @VictorPerdomo sImageID, Como es una variable byVal en vb lo tenían en String el List<Object> lo convertí que a mi concepto es lo mas cercano al collection que tenian

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa pero en el codigo VB el parametro ingresa como string? como se explica esto?

Comment: Es por que estas usando el método `Item` que funciona con un `Key` de la clase `Collection`, el parámetro de entrada para este método es un `String`. [Documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.item?view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_VisualBasic_Collection_Item_System_String_)

Comment: @VictorPerdomo entonces en tu ultima respuesta la mejor conversion de Collection de vb es un Dictionary<>???

Comment: Si puedes trabajarlo así, la verdad es que no estoy acostumbrado a convertir códigos lo ideal es que entiendas que hace cada cosa y busques la mejor manera de emularlo en el lenguaje que estés trabajando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[`ArrayList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.7.2) no tiene una propiedad `Items` para acceder a los elementos del array. Sin embargo puedes utilizar el [`acceso por indice`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.item?view=netframework-4.7.2) para obtener un elemento del array:

```
var sImageData = (ImageData)datosImagenes[0];
```

Comment: cambie tu respuesta Recuerda que en la pregunta esta es un List<>